# Python Setuptools build RPM error

Tags: python, linux, setuptools, rpmbuild

I am trying to build `RPM` package for python `setuptools-12.0.3` but getting wired error,

Its look like related to `SPEC` file `%files -f INSTALLED_FILES` but how to fix it? or is it a bug?  I can see two files path in single line, how do i fix it?

```
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
```

This is the command i am using `python2.7 setup.py bdist_rpm` to build RPM

```
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
Bytecompiling .py files below /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/setuptools-12.0.3/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-12.0.3-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6 using /usr/bin/python2.6
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: setuptools-12.0.3-1.noarch
error: Two files on one line: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/script
error: File must begin with "/": (dev).tmpl


RPM build errors:
    Two files on one line: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/script
    File must begin with "/": (dev).tmpl
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

After spending couple hours i figure out what was wrong:

copy `setuptools.spec` file in my own rpmbuild environment at `/root/rpmbuild/SPECS/`

Change `%files -f INSTALLED_FILES` to `%files`

Run `rpmbuild -ba setuptools.spec`

It generate list of files which need to add in `%files` section, But in that list there was one file which `space in filename` Ouch!!

`script (dev).tmpl`

I have used wildcard to match all files and problem solved. somehow `rpmbuild` doesn't understand `escap` character ( Don't know if there is a better way)

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
...
...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script*
```

...